# Possible to preload apps in supervisor mode and prevent them from being uninstalled?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, apple-configurator

I don't have a Mac or a personal Ipad to experiment with. I am trying to prevent a user from removing certain apps (not all apps). Can I stop the user from removing individual apps on a supervised device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop the user from deleting any app, or from deleting any Apple-system app.

You cannot with the current iOS stop the user from removing specific individual apps on a supervised device.